# struggling with creating a looped timer in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game where the player is a block of ice and naturally, the player will melt, and I decided to just decrease the players Y scale. The thing is though, I'm not sure how to set up the timer to do so. I know about Invoke, and tried to put Invoke in Update, but Invoke, once the timer is up, it just keep on running the loop, which is not what I want.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZCkI.png)

This diagram is sort of what I mean, I want the function to run every specified second(s), and once the code ran once, it restarts the loop, and in another second(s), it will run through the code again and so on.

Comment: Surely something like if (is melting) do countdown - deltatime, if countdown<=0 (countdown=1, melt)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a number of different ways to go about this. One of the most straight forward is just to use the Update method to increment a counter until a timeout is reached. I.e.

```
[SerializeField] private float timeout = 1f;

float _counter = 0f;

private void Update()
{
    _counter += Time.deltaTime;
    if (_counter >= timeout)
    {
        _counter -= timeout;
        // Now do something at timeout
        ...
    }
}
```

Another option would be to use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

```
void IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (true) // or e.g. check if player is alive
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
        // perform melted function here
        ...
    }
}
```

Yet another option would be to use [`MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). In your case, it would look something like:

```
[SerializeField] private float initialDelay = 1.0f;
[SerializeField] private float interval = 1.0f;

private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(Melted), initialDelay , interval);
}

private void Melted()
{
    // do your melted code
    ...
}
```